# Can I refer to the type parameter in an MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, type-parameter

Given a strongly typed view in ASP.Net MVC, is it possible to refer to the type parameter used to declare the view?

For example, if a page is declared as

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyProject.MyViewModel>" %>
```

is it possible to reference the type-parameter in `ViewPage<TModel>`?

I know I can do `Model.GetType()` but I have a situation where I have one view model derived from another, and both using the same view.  I currently have a line like

```
<% if (Model.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(MyViewModel)))
   { %>
```

to detect if the view is being used to display the derived model, but I'd like to be able to do it without hard-coding the `typeof(...)` call.

I want to do something like `Model.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(TModel))`

Comment: How else would you do it without hardcoding `MyViewModel`. Even if you could reference the Type param, you would still do `if(TModel is typeof(MyViewModel)...` something like that. You could pass around the type you want to check for in a variable of `Type` if you really want to go down this road.

Comment: @giddy: I want to do something like Model.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(TModel))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create your own base class you can expose the model type via a property:

```
public class BaseViewPage<TModel> : ViewPage<TModel>
{
    public Type ModelType { get { return typeof(TModel); } }
}
```

Change

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyProject.MyViewModel>" %>
```

to

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="MyProject.BaseViewPage<MyProject.MyViewModel>" %>
```

The model type is exposed via this.ModelType

Comment: Elegant.  I like it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the MSDN documentation on [ViewPage(TModel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470798.aspx):

> **Model** - Gets the Model property of the associated ViewDataDictionary object.

Grabbing the type from the Model property vis `Model.GetType()` is no more expensive than `TModel is typeof(X)`. As [Giddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368070/giddy) indicated, in his comment, there isn't real value in knowing the type of TModel as you will still have to make an if comparison.

That said I would be looking into your application architecture as there seems to be a code smell here. I am making an assumption, but it seems that you are utilizing the same view with two different models, but displaying different data depending on the model's type. To avoid issues like this I have my team follow the [one model per view rule](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/). This tends to keep your models and views succinct. Through effective use of partials you don't even feel the constraint.

Comment: It's a workflow application where most steps of the workflow just require accept/reject and some comments, but a few require additional data to be entered.  I've one view model for the majority case, and derived models with additional properties for the additional data.  This keeps the controller clean in that each step of the workflow is handled the same way.  The view just needs to detect if a derived view is being used, and then calls an associated partial view to render the additional form fields.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you an instance of the type object for TModel

```
this.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0]
```

.BaseType() is needed because 'this' actually corresponds to the class generated  for your .aspx view by asp.net at runtime.

So this.GetType().BaseType should give you the type object for System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage

Comment: +1 - Nice and straight forward, but I think Martin's wins on grounds of elegance.  Thanks anyway.